# On last record destroyed, add placeholder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to make sure that objects always have at least 1 image attached to them. So if a person deletes all the image belonging to an object, then it reverts to a default image.

What's the best way to go about this in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), there is an option to specify a [default_url](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/ClassMethods#has_attached_file-instance_method) for your image:

> default_url: The URL that will be returned if there is no attachment assigned. This field is interpolated just as the url is. The default value is "/:attachment/:style/missing.png"

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :default_url => "/images/default_:style_avatar.png"
User.new.avatar_url(:small) # => "/images/default_small_avatar.png"
```

Comment: I tried using this tactic, but with Carrierwave and it isn't working. Is it just supposed to magically revert to default on whatever attribute the uploader is mounted to if it's called with an empty file name?

Comment: This answer was specific to paperclip since you didn't tag or mention Carrierwave in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the record has a list of images. Without knowing your associations, I can only assume that you have a model called `Image` which belongs to `SomeOtherModel`.
In the view, you can just check for the existence of these images and render a different image if there's none.

```
if some_other_model.images.any?
  # render images here
else
  = image_tag 'placeholder.png'
```

one elegant solution might be to use placeholder.png as the background image (set to no-repeat) of the div containing the images.  just make sure that the div has a set height and that the first image always overlaps the background image.